# Ultisnips not working on first load of python file

Tags: filetype-python, plugin-ultisnips

I've installed the Ultisnips plugin with Pathogen. All in all it seems to be working fine.
My problem is that it doesn't seem to work for the first python file I load, but it works for all the rest.

That's a list of the plugins I currently have installed:

```
ctrlp.vim  nose.vim  syntastic  ultisnips       vim-easymotion  vim-snippets
jedi-vim   supertab  vim-commentary   vim-fugitive    vim-surround
```

Part of my .vimrc related to Ultisnips and SuperTab:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
let g:UltiSnipsUsePythonVersion = 2
" Set ultisnips triggers
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"                                            
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"                                       
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"
let g:ultisnips_python_style = "sphinx"
```

Has any one else encountered something similar?